# Complex sequense of number generation provides an unexpected product

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a project where I need to generate a random number (which is later modified). Currently I have this piece of code:

```py
x=input("x = ")

num1_child = randint(0,100)
num1.extend(str(num1_child))

num2 = randint(0,100)
if int(num1[n]) - num2 >= x:
   print(str(int(num1) - num2))
   print("yes \n")
   num_yes += 1
   Yes()
elif int(num1) - num2 <= -x:
   print(str(num2 - int(num1)))
   print("yes \n")
   num_yes += 1
   Yes()
else:        
   print(str(int(num1[n]) - num2) + "  //  " + str(num2 - int(num1)))
   print("no \n")
   num_no += 1
   No()
```

I want to generate a number between `1 and 100`, but it only generates a number netween `50 and 100`.

*just `randint(0, 100)` will not work in this usecase, it ahs to be set up using the `num1_child` etc.*

Comment: 'specific set of rules' --- what are they, could you describe?

Comment: What is the value of `x` ?

Comment: What are these "specific set of rules"? What is the first `input()` for? What are `Yes()` and `No()`? What number do you expect should be between 0 and 100?

Comment: @Lei Yang "The specific set of rules" are that is has to use the num1 as a list and num1_child, due to other parts of the code

Comment: @Pranav Hosangadi the input() is to wait for the user to press enter every eteration. Yes() and No() are functions should that do not interfere with the part of the code that is posted

Answer (score 0):

Its quite simple to generate random number-

Simplest way to make a float number between a range:

```py
import random
def makerandom(min,max):
  num = random.random()
  num = num * (max - min) + min
  return num
print(makerandom(0,100))
```

Get a random integer instead:

```py
import random
print(random.randint(0,100))
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no random number set that follows a "specific set of rules". A series of numbers can either be (pseudo) random or it can fullfill other specifications. You cannot combine both as per any "rule" you will reduce the entropy.